# Why Text is aligned to the top in mobile chrome, and is in the middle in chrome desktop?

Tags: html, css

Why is the text aligned to the top of the border in *mobile* Chrome, but is perfectly in the middle in *desktop* Chrome?

**mobile:**

[image]

**desktop:**

[image]

```css
.topbar {
  max-width: 600px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.logomain {
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <a class="logomain">BOOKS & DVD</a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could be line-height rendering differently. I would use some padding or flex to deal with positioning.

Comment: but how to set it without flex? why the same code is being red differently by the same browser? ive tried padding but that doesn't change the align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong (or peculiar) in the way this particular font "Luckiest Guy" is being displayed on mobile chrome. Ive changed the font and the display is the same now on both devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: flex;` for your `topbar` class. This way it will be easier to handle alignment of your items. Hope this code helps

```css
 .topbar {
    font-size: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }

.logomain {
    font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="topbar">
      <a class="logomain">BOOKS & DVD</a>
      <a></a>
      <a></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Things is i used flexbox below,i would have to rebuild the whole page now. Plus i really want to find answer to this change in chrome display.